# Can email be deleted from your users' Gmail inboxes programmatically via API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, google-workspace

The ["Find and delete malicious emails"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7581662) page in the Google Workspace Admin Help Center states:

> Using the investigation tool, you can identify all users in your domain that have received the message (for example, a phishing email). You can then use the investigation tool to delete the email from your users' Gmail inboxes (note that log data might take up to a few minutes before being available in the investigation tool).

From this, I understand that, assuming you have the right package, it is possible to use the investigation tool to delete the unwanted email from your users' Gmail inboxes.

Can I delete emails from my users' Gmail inboxes via Google App Script using the API? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Currently it is not possible with the Investigation tool

But there is already an existing [feature request for exposing the Google Workspace Investigation Tool programmatically](https://issuetracker.google.com/179694584).

I recommend you to "star" it to show Google that more people are interested in this feature - hopefully this will accelerate the implementation.

UPDATE:

In th meantime you can use a workaround, e.g. using a service account with domain-wide delegation as suggested by @TheAddonDepot

Comment: This is incorrect. It is possible to delete email across all user via domain-wide delegation. See answer below.

Comment: This is true, there are workarounds. But the user was asking about either this is possible with the Investigation tool - and the respective endpoint has not been programmatically implemented yet.

Comment: can we agree on this not being *directly* possible as a middle ground and amend the answer accordingly? domain-wide delegation + service account is a valid solution but is probably more effort than the OP expects. Off-note: heya, @ziganotschka!

Comment: Hello @OlegValter! Your suggestion sounds good, I will modify my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

### It is possible via DwDg(domain-wide delegation)

You have to create a service account and delegate domain-wide authority to that service account with the appropriate scopes. There are no explicit instructions for the Gmail API but you can use [this guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) from the Admin Directory API documentation.

You then use the [service account credentials with the GAS OAuth2 Library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2#using-service-accounts) to make calls on behalf of your existing users to the Gmail API. Note that you can't use the built-in or advanced services for Gmail, you'll have to call out to the Gmail REST API directly via `UrlFetchApp`.